python pandas simple row numbering on monthly basis
I am failing to find a solution for trading research.
I have a large dataset of market data running from 1993-2024.
Since calendar days do not match the trading days. It might be implemented by "business days", but who knows if holidays/business days match the trading days. I need to get a trading day of month if certain conditions are met.
                  Day        Open        High         Low       Close     Volume  trading_day
Date
2010-01-04     Monday  112.370003  113.389999  111.510002  113.330002  118944600            1
2010-01-05    Tuesday  113.260002  113.680000  112.849998  113.629997  111579900            2
2010-01-06  Wednesday  113.519997  113.989998  113.430000  113.709999  116074400            3
2010-01-07   Thursday  113.500000  114.330002  113.180000  114.190002  131091100            4
2010-01-08     Friday  113.889999  114.620003  113.660004  114.570000  126402800            5
2010-01-11     Monday  115.080002  115.129997  114.239998  114.730003  106375700            6
2010-01-12    Tuesday  113.970001  114.209999  113.220001  113.660004  163333500            7
2010-01-13  Wednesday  113.949997  114.940002  113.370003  114.620003  161822000            8
2010-01-14   Thursday  114.489998  115.139999  114.419998  114.930000  115718800            9
2010-01-15     Friday  114.730003  114.839996  113.199997  113.639999  212283100           10
2010-01-19    Tuesday  113.620003  115.129997  113.589996  115.059998  139172700           11
2010-01-20  Wednesday  114.279999  114.449997  112.980003  113.889999  216490200           12
2010-01-21   Thursday  113.919998  114.269997  111.559998  111.699997  344859600           13
2010-01-22     Friday  111.199997  111.739998  109.089996  109.209999  345942400           14
2010-01-25     Monday  110.209999  110.410004  109.410004  109.769997  186937500           15
2010-01-26    Tuesday  109.339996  110.470001  109.040001  109.309998  211168800           16
2010-01-27  Wednesday  109.169998  110.080002  108.330002  109.830002  271863600           17
2010-01-28   Thursday  110.190002  110.250000  107.910004  108.570000  316104000           18
2010-01-29     Friday  109.040001  109.800003  107.220001  107.389999  310677600           19

Above by is an example what I am trying to achieve. I managed that by selecting one month for testing purpose with following code.
df_test['trading_day'] = range(1, len(df_test) + 1)
Of course, there are about 300+ months since 1993 so it would be hell to do it all manually.
I managed to df.groupby by month with the following code:
df_grouped_monthly = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')) and tried to apply same counter as above by. Sadly, it doesn't work on grouped df. I tried .transform(add(1))
Possible solutions are either get grouped row position - no idea whether row number is inherited from initial df, or it is counted based on groupby.
Or add above by mentioned counter to grouped df. I failed to add extra column to grouped df.
Any suggestions how to achieve above by df on whole dataset based on monthly basis, please?

This question is similar to: Add a sequential counter column on groups to a pandas dataframe. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

As per the suggested duplicate, you seem to be looking for df['trading_day'] = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='ME')).cumcount().add(1).

You can convert the 'Date' column to datetime and create new column before grouping.
df["Month"] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%b', errors='coerce').dt.month

Output DateFrame:
 Date   Day         Open    High    Low Close   Volume  Month
2010-01-04  Monday  112.370003  113.389999  111.510002  113.330002  118944600   1
2010-01-05  Tuesday 113.260002  113.68  112.849998  113.629997  111579900   1
2010-01-06  Wednesday   113.519997  113.989998  113.43  113.709999  116074400   1
2010-01-07  Thursday    113.5   114.330002  113.18  114.190002  131091100   1
2010-01-08  Friday  113.889999  114.620003  113.660004  114.57  126402800   1
2010-01-11  Monday  115.080002  115.129997  114.239998  114.730003  106375700   1
2010-01-12  Tuesday 113.970001  114.209999  113.220001  113.660004  163333500   1
2010-01-13  Wednesday   113.949997  114.940002  113.370003  114.620003  161822000   1
2010-01-14  Thursday    114.489998  115.139999  114.419998  114.93  115718800   1
2010-01-15  Friday  114.730003  114.839996  113.199997  113.639999  212283100   1
2010-01-19  Tuesday 113.620003  115.129997  113.589996  115.059998  139172700   1
2010-01-20  Wednesday   114.279999  114.449997  112.980003  113.889999  216490200   1
2010-01-21  Thursday    113.919998  114.269997  111.559998  111.699997  344859600   1
2010-01-22  Friday  111.199997  111.739998  109.089996  109.209999  345942400   1
2010-01-25  Monday  110.209999  110.410004  109.410004  109.769997  186937500   1
2010-01-26  Tuesday 109.339996  110.470001  109.040001  109.309998  211168800   1
2010-01-27  Wednesday   109.169998  110.080002  108.330002  109.830002  271863600   1
2010-01-28  Thursday    110.190002  110.25  107.910004  108.57  316104000   1
2010-01-29  Friday  109.040001  109.800003  107.220001  107.389999  310677600   1
2010-02-04  Saturday    109.040001  109.800003  107.220001  107.389999  310677600   2
2010-02-05  Sunday  109.040001  109.800003  107.220001  107.389999  310677600   2
2010-02-06  Monday  109.040001  109.800003  107.220001  107.389999  310677600   2
2010-02-07  Tuesday 109.040001  109.800003  107.220001  107.389999  310677600   2
2010-02-08  Wednesday   109.040001  109.800003  107.220001  107.389999  310677600   2
2010-02-09  Thursday    109.040001  109.800003  107.220001  107.389999  310677600   2
2010-02-10  Friday  109.040001  109.800003  107.220001  107.389999  310677600   2
2010-02-11  Saturday    109.040001  109.800003  107.220001  107.389999  310677600   2
2010-02-12  Sunday  109.040001  109.800003  107.220001  107.389999  310677600   2
2010-02-13  Monday  109.040001  109.800003  107.220001  107.389999  310677600   2
2010-02-14  Tuesday 109.040001  109.800003  107.220001  107.389999  310677600   2
2010-02-15  Wednesday   109.040001  109.800003  107.220001  107.389999  310677600   2
2010-02-16  Thursday    109.040001  109.800003  107.220001  107.389999  310677600   2
2010-02-17  Friday  109.040001  109.800003  107.220001  107.389999  310677600   2

You can use this modified dataframe to find the information you are looking for.
 #For instance, adding 'trading_Day' column
 df['Trading_day']= df.groupby(['Month'], sort=True).cumcount()+1

Output:
       Date  Day        Month     Trading_day
0  2010-01-04     Monday      1            1
1  2010-01-05    Tuesday      1            2
2  2010-01-06  Wednesday      1            3
3  2010-01-07   Thursday      1            4
4  2010-01-08     Friday      1            5
5  2010-01-11     Monday      1            6
6  2010-01-12    Tuesday      1            7
7  2010-01-13  Wednesday      1            8
8  2010-01-14   Thursday      1            9
9  2010-01-15     Friday      1           10
10 2010-01-19    Tuesday      1           11
11 2010-01-20  Wednesday      1           12
12 2010-01-21   Thursday      1           13
13 2010-01-22     Friday      1           14
14 2010-01-25     Monday      1           15
15 2010-01-26    Tuesday      1           16
16 2010-01-27  Wednesday      1           17
17 2010-01-28   Thursday      1           18
18 2010-01-29     Friday      1           19
19 2010-02-04   Saturday      2            1
20 2010-02-05     Sunday      2            2
21 2010-02-06     Monday      2            3
22 2010-02-07    Tuesday      2            4
23 2010-02-08  Wednesday      2            5
24 2010-02-09   Thursday      2            6
25 2010-02-10     Friday      2            7
26 2010-02-11   Saturday      2            8
27 2010-02-12     Sunday      2            9
28 2010-02-13     Monday      2           10
29 2010-02-14    Tuesday      2           11
30 2010-02-15  Wednesday      2           12
31 2010-02-16   Thursday      2           13
32 2010-02-17     Friday      2           14

You can then perform your analysis.
# When is Closing value > Opening Value
grouped_df = df.query("Close >= Open")[['Month', 'trading_day']]
print(grouped_df)

Output:
        Month  trading_day
0       1            1
1       1            2
2       1            3
3       1            4
4       1            5
7       1            8
8       1            9
10      1           11
16      1           17


Date is already pandas datetime index.
What are extra Year, Month, Day columns for, please?

I updated the response with an example. Is this what you are looking for? If not, can you clarify what you need?

thanks for reply chief.
I do not know how to exactly define the problem. I did some UTFG, RTFM, but I always get wrong answer. I am asking probably wrong.
Example of market data query
If Close > Open, what trading_day is that
This condition is true for 2010-01-06  Wednesday for example. It is trading day 5 or row[4]

now imagine there are almost 8000 rows
this query must filter/sort only on monthly basis

Does the updated example provide a suitable solution for you?

do not forget, the column "trading_day" doesn't exist yet.
That is my question. How to generate trading_day column on a monthly basis.
Queries/grouping is simple afterwards.

I updated the solution with that information.
